# Is there a maximum version number in hbase?

Tags: hbase

If I want to insert in a table:

```
row | fam:qualifier | timestamp | value
1 | foo:bar | 12345 | 2
1 | foo:bar | 12346 | 3
1 | foo:bar | 12347 | 2
1 | foo:bar | 12348 | 1
.
.
. 
1 | foo:bar | 123410 | 2
```

I can specify in the hbase shell the maximum number of version to get fom a specific row but when I specify for instance '100' it return me only 4 versions... 
Is there any maximum?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It only returns 4 versions because the column family is set to store a maximum of 4 versions.

If you want to store more versions you need to alter the CF. Using the hbase shell:

```
hbase> alter 'table_foo', {NAME => 'column_fam_foo', VERSIONS => 100}
```

The default for max versions is 1*:

http://hbase.apache.org/book/schema.versions.html

*It seems the default value for max versions was changed from 3 to 1 at some point.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is partly right. Not true: hbase STORES three versions. Proof see below. 
True: you can set the maximum amount of versions which hbase returns through

```
alter 'marketdata', NAME => 'field', VERSIONS => 100
```

But for now let's assume, I didn't change the version variable.

I have ten entries in my hbase, with timestamps from 0 to 9. 
The most current timestamp is:

```
hbase(main):025:0> get 'marketdata', 'instrument1', {COLUMN => 'field:ask'}                                 
COLUMN                             CELL                                                                                   
 field:ask                     timestamp=9,         value=0.9940174211042572                                                  
1 row(s) in 0.0590 seconds

hbase(main):026:0>
```

The values from timestamp 1 to 5 that are shown are:

```
hbase(main):027:0> get 'marketdata', 'instrument1', {COLUMN => 'field:ask', TIMERANGE => [0,5], VERSIONS=>5}
COLUMN                             CELL                                                                                   
 field:ask                     timestamp=4, value=0.530618878519702                                                   
 field:ask                     timestamp=3, value=0.051028316270589014                                                
 field:ask                     timestamp=2,     value=0.11949750640509116                                                 
3 row(s) in 0.0130 seconds

hbase(main):028:0>
```

... and when i set my end timestamp to 10, it still shows only the last three versions BEFORE that timestamp and suppresses the former ones:

```
hbase(main):028:0> get 'marketdata', 'instrument1', {COLUMN => 'field:ask', TIMERANGE => [0,10], VERSIONS=>5}
COLUMN                             CELL                                                                                   
 field:ask                     timestamp=9,     value=0.9940174211042572                                                  
 field:ask                     timestamp=8,     value=0.6941263513176372                                                  
 field:ask                     timestamp=7,     value=0.1814043435754933                                                  
3 row(s) in 0.0400 seconds

hbase(main):029:0>
```

Comment: wait, so how can you see version 4,3,2 and 9,8,7 if hbase is only storing 3 versions?  Perhaps the shell is only returning 3, for whatever reason, but your seem to have 'proved' that there are more versions.  The real answer is also more complicated because of the way hbase deletes versions: it doesn't really.  If you explicitly delete data it will add a tombstone and you won't see any data before the tombstone. All other data will be available (and all data will be stored) until the next major compaction which will rewrite the store file and only keep the correct number of versions.

Comment: Hi David, you downvoted based on an edited response by codingFoo.

Comment: This answer is still a little misleading.  What you are missing is the compaction issue.  When HBase stores a value, it just appends it to the file.  It never deletes data.  To implement delete, they append a tombstone that essentially says that a value should be ignored.  Now, when a compaction comes along, the file will be re-written, and neither old versions or deleted versions will be rewritten to the new file.  So, there is a time window when you will be able to see the old versions, but that time window is limited and you should not rely on old versions being there.

Answer (score 0):

Concept of version is tightly maintained at column family level . Its a configurable parameter .

```
            columnFamily.setMaxVersions(required version);
```

The more versions one has,  while fetching  chances of reading data from multiple HFiles increases .

The best way would be to maintain minimum version and encapsulate data in one single blob .